# jQuery upload and preview image onchange through ajax without submitting the whole form

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I am trying to do is to keep the form as it is by showing uploaded images until it's posted, because images can have titles. (Like Facebook status updates)

There are a few inputs in my form, so I can't use .on('change') for upload only. The one below is an excerpt because my form is quite a long one.

I didn't include my php file because it's very long and it works if I use #uploadForm instead of #uploadimages

The question is, how can I submit only images before submitting form? (Because I want my users to be able to see the preview of the pictures they upload)

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="statustext" name="statustext"></textarea>
    <label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
    <input id="uploadimages" name="images[]" type="file" multiple class="inputFile hidden"/>
    <div class="button" id="trigger">Upload File</div>
</form>
```

Ajax part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#uploadimages").on('change', (function (e) { // Why it doesn't work?
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "form.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#targetLayer").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
            }));
        });

        $("#trigger").click(function(){
            $("#uploadimages").click();
        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}

.button {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #777;
    color: #fff;
    width:75px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyIW/tbe1xbzn/

I've created a new upload form for you to work from, you'll need to add an image of a cross that is added everytime a new image is added and placed next to it (x.png). All of this is done locally, you can preview the image instantly and then submit the form when you're complete with adding images. See fiddle.

HTML

```
<div id="formdiv">
                    <h1 class="uploadH2">Upload Your Artwork</h1>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">


                    <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>


                    <input type="button" class="add_more" id="add_more" value="Add More Files"/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="img_upload" class="show-page-loading-msg" data-theme="b" data-textonly="false" data-textvisible="false" data-msgtext="" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"/>

                </form>

                <br/>

        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var abc = 0; //Declaring and defining global increement variable

$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
                $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),        
                $("<br/><br/>")
                ));
    });

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file   
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                 abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

                var z = abc - 1;
                var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src='' style='width:40%; height:40%;'/></div>");

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                $(this).hide();
                $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'delete', src: 'x.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }));
            }
        });

//To preview image     
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    $('#upload').click(function(e) {
        var name = $(":file").val();
        if (!name)
        {
            alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
font-family:sans-serif;
color:black;
margin:0;
background-image:url(../img/upload.png);
}

#formdiv{
width:100%;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
}
form{
    padding: 40px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width:100%;
}
.upload{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px green;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
}
.upload:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#c20b0b;
    border:1px solid #c20b0b;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
}

.uploadH2{margin-top:3%; font-size:36px;}

#file{
    color:green;
    padding:5px; border:1px dashed #123456;
    background-color: #f9ffe5;
}
#img_upload{
    margin-left: 45px;
}

#noerror{
    color:green;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: left;
}
#error{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: left;
}
#image img{ 
    width: 10%;
    border: none; 
    height:10%;
}

.abcd{
    text-align: center;
}

.abcd #previewimg {
    width:10%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.abcd #delete{
    width:3%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
b{
    color:red;
}
```

If you require more or anything else, ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Try out 3rd party libraries for uploading files asynchronously. This worked out very well for me: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I've downloaded it last week, tried to make it work but it looked very complicated for me and I gave up. I'll look it into again, thanks.